Get SteamVR controller Rotation and Apply to animator float value 0 to 1 with sensibility adjust
Im working on DJ equipment for VRchat world, and I want to move a Knob pressing trigger and rotating them with VR controller, but I dont have knowlege how I make a Script on Udon Sharp that gets VRcontroller rotation and apply to Float Parameter, to move an Animation that rotates the knob by specific angle to other specific angle..
I have no ideia how to make a Script :/
